# Securely store data on Android version 16 and above

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

I have an android application that need to support version 16 and above. In that I have to store a licence string securely on the device.

My initial thoughts was using KeyStore to generate the key pairs and store encrypted licence string on shared preferences. But came to find out KeyStore is available only on Versions 18 and above.

Android keyChain is available on version 14 and above. But from what I read KeyChain is meant to store certificates securely. But I have seen some samples which stores some keys into keychain [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.security.KeyChain) .

I am completely newbie in secure storage,whats teh best option to securely store my licence string on android device considering that I have to support versions 16 and above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tough problem. KeyChain is intended as a system-wide key storage system. This means that all users (which should be no problem in older android versions as those are only single-user) and all applications could access the keychain. And that "all application" part is a problem for your use-case.

Can you query users for some sort of credentials (e.g., password)? If so, you could use that password to encrypt/decrypt the certificate using some standard encryption theme (AES-GCM or similar) and store the encrypted data in your appliation's storage area.